# How to set custom delegate to UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates, protocols

One cell in my tableview takes me to another UITableViewController where I have to select one option.
I tried to set the first viewcontroller as delegate of the UITableViewController but it's not working, and I need to pass the chosen data. 
I think it's not working because for UITableViewControllers you don't set the delegate because they're automatically their own delegates. 
So how can I do it?
I go back by `self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)`  so I don't lose the information that'd already been filled in the first viewcontroller. 
Is there a way to set a custom delegate for UITableViewController or should I just put the tableview in a regular viewcontroller?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting `delegate` of your `UITableView` as your first controller. Don't do that, this `delegate` is already set by default as this `UITableViewController`.

---

Instead, for passing data use callback closure:

```
class TVC: UITableViewController {

    var itemSelected: (Item) -> Void = { _ in }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        itemSelected(dataSourceArray[indexPath.row])
    }
}
```

and in first view controller set closure of this controller when you're presenting/pushing it

```
let vc = TVC(...)
vc.itemSelected = { item in // this is called when you call `itemSelected` from `TVC`
    // ... declare what will happen after item is selected
}
navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Or if you're using segues

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "identifier" {
        let destination = segue.destination as! TVC
        destination.itemSelected = { item in
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not using segue so I tried the first version, but I don't understand the **TVC(...)**. What should be inside the **()**? Also, I'm not exactly presenting the first VC because it was already presented, I'm just popping the TVC because I only know this way to keep the information I already had in my first VC. So when should I call the closure? Thank you!

Comment: @ManuelLagunaMatias inside `TVC(...)` should be instantiating your controller. I don't know how you're initalizing (this is why I used ...). Anyway, this is moment when you're presenting new controller/ pushing it via navigation controller. So this is moment when you have first and you're pushing `UITableViewController`

Comment: woow this is awesome!! Sorry, I was misunderstanding. The thing is I was just 'performing segue" from inside a cell inside first VC tableView, but now I got you and it's working pretty well. Thanks!! =D